# Check convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\cos^{n^3}\frac1{\sqrt n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\cos^{n^3}\frac1{\sqrt n}$$
This is the first time that I'm learning about the convergence of the series and there are so many theorems about how to prove one and I really don't know which one to use.

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: What does $n3$ mean? It makes a huge difference whether you mean $3n$ or $n^3$.

Comment: it's $n^3$ . I edited it

Comment: I don't think there are "so many" theorems.  When you have an $n$th power (or worse) then the root test suggests itself.

Comment: I said I'm new to this. I am trying to learn which theorem should I use for specific problems

Comment: @J.Dane When proving convergence of series, one of the best tools in my opinion is using the comparison test. There are a bunch of series (geometric, harmonic, alternating harmonic, etc) which have already been proven to converge or diverge. If you are looking to prove convergence for a series A, you can compare it to a series B where every term in B is larger than the the terms in A. If B converges, then A must also converge. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!

Comment: And I told you which theorem to use and why.  Who knows why you'd have a problem with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We need neither the root test nor Taylor's Theorem to proceed.  Here instead, we use the elementary inequalities $\log(1-x)\le -x$ and $\sin(x)\ge 2x/\pi$ (for $0<x\le \pi/2$).

---

Proceeding, we see that for $n\ge1$

$$\begin{align}
0\le \cos^{n^3}(n^{-1/2})&=e^{n^3\log(1-2\sin^2(n^{-1/2}/2))}\\\\
&\le e^{-2n^3\sin^2(n^{-1/2}/2)}\\\\
&\le e^{-2n^2/\pi^2}\\\\
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-2n^2/\pi^2}$ converges, we conclude that the series of interest converges also.

Comment: Very nice and elegant solution!

Comment: @gimusi Thank you!  Much appreciated.

Comment: Would the down voter care to comment???'

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)\right)^{n^3}= \left(1-\frac1{2n}+\frac1{24n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)^{n^3}=e^{n^3\log{\left(1-\frac1{2n}+\frac1{24n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)}}\sim e^{-\frac{n^2}2}$$

therefore the given series converges by limit comparison test with $\sum e^{-\frac{n^2}2}$.

As an alternative by [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) for $a_n=\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)\right)^{n^3}$ we have

$$\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)\right)^{n^2}\sim e^{-\frac{n}2}\to 0$$

Comment: I don’t understand the downvote.

Comment: @Szeto Thanks for your opinion, I was wondering the same and looking for the mistake! So you agree with that way to solve?

Comment: Maybe it got downvoted, because the solution is not elementary enough?

Comment: Note there are two close votes on the question (for a totally silly reason, imo). It can happen that an answer gets downvoted simply bbecause people disapprove of answering "bad" questions...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich On the other han some kind of elementary questions very poorly posed are ignored, as for example (and only as an example) https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2862389/505767

Comment: I wasn't saying it was right, or consistent, just pointing out a possible reason for the downvote. Heh, there's a difference of opinion regarding the limit in the root test - maybe someone thought yours was wrong (it's right).

Comment: @MarkViola I need to learn from you the way to use inequalities for series, you know that I'm "LCT" addicted :P

Comment: Limit comparison test :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest here is to use the *root test*: you should find the
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\biggl(\cos^{n^3}\!\frac1{\sqrt n}\biggr)^{\!\tfrac1n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^{n^2}\!\frac1{\sqrt n}=0.$$

**Hint**:

This is equivalent to showing $\;\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\log\biggl(\cos\dfrac1{\sqrt n}\biggr)=-\infty$, and you can use for that Taylor formula at order $2$:
$$\cos u=1-\frac{u^2}2+o(u^2).$$

Comment: I think it should be $n^2$ not $1/n^2$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: You're right. I should always check computations with a pencil and paper before posting, but I didn't. I've fixed the answer. Thank you for pointing the  error!

Answer (score 0):

In style to @MarkViola's version. [Here is a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795803/how-to-see-cos-x-leq-exp-x2-2-on-x-in-0-pi-2/1795885#1795885) of
$$0\leq\cos{x}\leq e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}, \forall x\in \left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$$
using nothing but derivatives, so may be classified as elementary.
Also, $0<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<\frac{\pi}{2}, \forall n >0$. Then
$$0\leq\cos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\leq e^{-\frac{1}{2n}}\Rightarrow
0\leq \left(\cos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\right)^{n^3}\leq e^{-\frac{n^2}{2}} \tag{1}$$
and finally
$$0\leq \sum\limits_{n=1} \left(\cos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\right)^{n^3}\leq \sum\limits_{n=1}e^{-\frac{n^2}{2}}$$