# Find all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^5$ such that $S$ is an orthogonal set. Express answer as a linear span.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Find all vectors (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) in  $\mathbb{R}^5$ such that S = {(1, 1, 1, 2, 0) , (0, 0, −2, 1, 0) , (0, 0, 0, 0, 1) , (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)} is an orthogonal set. Express your answer as a linear span.

Clue was given to form a homogeneous system and solve it. I have tried solving

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrrr|r}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
  \end{array}\right]
$$

Attempt at a solution:

$$
x_2 = s  ,\,\,\, x_4 = t , \,\, where\,\, s,t \in \mathbb{R}, \\
x_1 = -s - \frac{5t}{2} , \, \, \, x_3 = \frac{t}{2}, \,\,\,x_5 = 0
\\\therefore\\(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) = (-s - \frac{5t}{2},\,\,\,s,\,\,\,\frac{t}{2},\,\,\,t,\,\,\,0)  
$$

But how do I answer in terms of linear span form here on?

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

EDIT:

With help from @Gerry's comments I got to

$$
(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) = span{\{(-1,1,0,0,0),(\frac{-5}{2},0, \frac{1}{2},1,0)\} }
$$

Comment: I think you're absolutely right that $S$ has vectors in it that are not orthogonal so there's no way to extend it to be orthogonal. Also, note that all those vectors are in ${\bf R}^5$, so where does ${\bf R}^2$ come in?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have requested clarification for the question and have fixed the question. It is now valid but I still am not sure how to proceed

Comment: Now take your vector and write it as $(a,b,c,d,e)s+(f,g,h,i,j)t$ for appropriate numbers $a,b,\dots,j$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Updated my question body with an attempted solution with your help. I know I should never answer my own question, perhaps you could write a short answer verifying my attempt so that this question won't be stuck in limbo?

Comment: On the contrary, QzSG, you are explicitly encouraged to answer your own questions. Let me encourage you to write up what you have found, and to post it as an answer. It's good practice!

Comment: Today would be a good day to do that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Comment: I was away for a few days in the wild with no internet connection and I have abandoned my question? Wow..

Comment: Welcome back, QzSG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My path to getting a solution.

We know that for orthogonal sets, any distinct pair has their dot product equals to zero
ie $ u_i.u_j = 0 \,\, for \,\,\,i \neq j $

The matrix way of doing that is simply 
$$
u_iu_j^T 
$$
Set up the system 
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrrr}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -2 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}\right]
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrrr}
    x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 \\
  \end{array}\right]^T
  = 0
$$

Solve augmented matrix
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrrr|r}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
  \end{array}\right]
$$
Results
$$
x_2 = s  ,\,\,\, x_4 = t , \,\, where\,\, s,t \in \mathbb{R}, \\
x_1 = -s - \frac{5t}{2} , \, \, \, x_3 = \frac{t}{2}, \,\,\,x_5 = 0
\\\therefore\\(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) = (-s - \frac{5t}{2},\,\,\,s,\,\,\,\frac{t}{2},\,\,\,t,\,\,\,0)  
$$ 
Convert to linear span => Solution :
$$
(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) = span{\{(-1,1,0,0,0),(\frac{-5}{2},0, \frac{1}{2},1,0)\} }
$$

Answer (score 0):

The vector $\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ is obviously orthogonal to all vectors given. Then using the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix), as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2863808), we get a last orthogonal vector, $\begin{bmatrix}5&5&-2&-4&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Thus, an orthogonal basis for the subspace orthogonal to the three vectors given in the question is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0&0&0\\5&5&-2&-4&0\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Sorry, I have not gone as far as basis, and subspaces yet. Could you explain why your answer looks different from the one i got?

Comment: The vectors I gave are orthogonal to each other, but the vectors in your answer span the same subspace. Note that the first vector in my list is the negative of yours. If we take $5$ times my first vector plus my second vector, we get $\begin{bmatrix}10&0&-2&-4&0\end{bmatrix}$, which is $4$ times your second vector.